# Tranfer csv file from sftp server to ftp server using file.sh

Tags: ftp, sh, sftp, centos7

I'm setting up for a cron job , in the cronjob.sh i need to tranfer the csv file from server sftp to ftp server , any idea or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write a shell script (.sh) file that does the job.

Assuming both your servers are linux nodes with scp enabled, try a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# we assume ssh gen-rsa is used to generate id_rsa_1 and id_rsa_2 
# for username1 and username2 for host1 and host2 respectively.

cd /path/to/id_rsa/files
# download the file
scp -i id_rsa_1 usename1@host1:/path/to/your/csv/file.csv ./
# upload the file
scp -i id_rsa_2 ./file.csv username2@host2:/path/to/destination/directory/
```

The above can be run via commandline as:

```
chmod 755 my_bash.sh
./my_bash.sh
```

Verify if the file transfer is working.

Then, invoke my_bash.sh in your crontab -e editor.

Comment: if i do the script like that, did i need to put the username and password when it run ?,because if can i want it to be fully auto including putting the username and password ..@Edward Aung

Comment: best practice is to use ssl. that is why there is no password there but the commands have -i id_rsa_x options.